# How to get text between div tags that contain class, style etc attributes before id attribute. I need to use regular expression

Tags: php, html, regex

Hi I'm using this regular expression for getting the text inside test

```
<div id = "test">text</div>

$regex = "#\<div id=\"test\"\>(.+?)\<\/div\>#s";
```

But if the scenario change for e.g.

```
<div class="testing" style="color:red" .... more attributes and id="test">text</div>
```

or

```
<div class="testing" ...some attributes... id="test".... some attributes....>text</div>
```

or

```
<div id="test" .........any number of attributes>text</div>
```

then the above regex will not be able to extract the text between div tag. In 1st case if more attributes are placed in front of id attribute of div tag i.e id attribute being the last attribute the above regex don work. In second case id attribute is between some attributes and in 3rd case it is the 1st attribute of div tag.
Can I have a regex that can match the above 3 conditions so as to extract the text between div tags by **specifying ID ONLY**. Have to use regex only :( .

Please Help

Thank you....

Comment: Do you really need to use regex for that? Why don't you use a parser like DOM?

Comment: This must be the most duplicated question on SO. Always the same answer: DON'T REGEX TO PARSE HTML! I give up...

Answer (score 4):

I would strongly recommend [an HTML parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to save yourself from the [never-ending grief of trying to write a regular expression to parse HTML/XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Parsing HTML the cthulhu Way (eheheh)  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: I understand I have the code by using DOM but due to the architecture in my project I can't use DOM so choice

Comment: As far as I know, DOM is included in PHP4, as well as PHP5. Is it homework or something? why can't you use DOM? Just curious... (i honestly can't think of any reason beyond regex homework or something)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you obtain that DOM element via xpath, the xpath expression for that element is:

```
//div[@class="testing"]
```

All this can be done with the PHP DOMDocument extension or alternatively with the SimpleXML extension. Both ship in 99,9% with PHP, same as with the regular expression extension, some rough example code ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/RWwxNE)):

```
echo simplexml_import_dom(@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html))
         ->xpath('//div[@class="testing"]')[0];
```

Xpath is a specialized language for querying elements and data from XML documents, where as regular expression is a language for more simple strings.

**Edit:** Same for ID: http://codepad.viper-7.com/h1FlO0

```
//div[@id="test"]
```

I guess you understand quite quickly how these simple xpath expressions work.

Comment: Thanks for knowledge sharing :)
but in my case my architecture don't allow me to use xpath or even DOM any help via Regular Expression ???

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer with DOM (kind of crudish but works)

```
$aPieceOfHTML = '<div class="testing" id="test" style="color:red">This is my text blabla<div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($aPieceOfHTML);
$div = $doc->getElementsByTagName("div");
$mytext = $div->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo $mytext;
```

---

Here's the Cthulhu way:

```
$regex = '/(?<=id\=\"test\"\>).*(?=\<\/div\>)/';
```

**DISCLAIMER**
By no means I guarantee this will work in every case (far from it). In fact, this will fail if:

1. `id="test"` is not the last tag attribute
2. if there is a space (or anything) between `id="test"` and the closing `>`.
3. If the div tag is not properly closed `</div>`
4. If the tags are written in uppercase
5. If tag attributes are written in uppercase
6. I don't know... this will probably fail in more cases

I could try to write a more complex regex but I don't think I could come up with something much better than this. Besides, it kind of seems a waste of time when you have other tools built in PHP that can parse HTML so much better.

Comment: can you help me vi Regex ....... project architecture is not supporting dom or xpath :( 
Thanks for a quick reply

Comment: Thanks a lot Tivie ......... this some how helped me :) 
Will be looking for your help in future as well ..... Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need this, but the RegEx below works for all of the give scenarios in your question.

```
(!?(<.*?>)|[^<]+)\s*
```

https://regex101.com/r/DAObw0/1

The matching group can be accessed with:

```
const [_, group1, group2] = myRegex.Exec(input)
```